# Binomial Coefficients-Squares

Tags: binomial-coefficients

A discrete random variable $X$ takes value $0,1,2, \ldots n$ with frequency  $\binom{n}{0}, \binom{n}{1}, \ldots, \binom{n}{n}$. Find the variance.

I have calculated the mean as such 
$$\mathbb{P}(X)= \binom{n}{x}/2^n$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}(X)
 &= \binom{n}{1}/2^n+ \binom{n}{2}/2^n + \ldots + \binom{n}{n}/2^n\\
 &= \frac{\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + \ldots + \binom{n}{n}}{2^n}\\
 &=  \frac{n \cdot 2^{n-1}}{2^n}\\
 &= n/2
\end{split}
$$
But
$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)
 = \binom{1}{1}/2^n+ \binom{4}{2}/2^n + \ldots
$$

I am not able to get an algebraic expression for this series.
I know the answer is $n/4$.

Comment: I tried to make this readable, please verify this is what you intended.

Comment: If this is the binomial with probability of success $1/2$, the probability that $X=k$ is, in your notation, ${}_n\text{C}_k$. The *expression* for the mean is as of now not correct, though $n/2$ is correct. The expression for $E(X^2)$ is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the mean should be
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k /2^n = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k
$$
and similarly
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k^2
$$

Can you take it from here?

**HINT** one more word about how to handle such sums. You derived the probability distribution correctly, so you know that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$. A more general form of that is the Binomial Theorem
$$
(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k
$$
(you get your result for $x=1$). Note that taking the first derivative we get
$$
n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}
$$
and substitution of $x=1$ makes things much more simple. Try another differentiation to handle the second moment.